# I need to get arrow key presses, but keyDown won't call (Swift)

Tags: swift, keydown

I am trying to build a Mac App which displays images and I want to move on to the next image when I press the right arrow key. I have looked all over stackoverflow and the internet, but just can't seem to get it.

**What I tried...** I tried to use `keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent)`but it does not call when I press any keys. I believe this is because it is not in a text field of some kind, but not sure.

**What Happens...** When i'm testing the program, I press a key (with keyDown function ready to `println("Key Pressed")`) and I get the OS X reject noise and no println to the console.

I have heard of some people subclassing NSView to override `acceptsFirstResponder`, but I am new to subclassing so any direction you could point me in would be great. Or if there is a way to do it w/o subclassing NSView that would be great!

Thanks in advance! Sorry for the noobness.

Comment: Where do you want to capture the Key Down event? `NSWindow`, `NSTableView`, `NSButton`? Also, please post what you have tried.

Comment: @ZoffDino I have deleted what I tried earlier. I believe I want to capture the event at NSView, but i'm not for sure on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclassing is less difficult than it seems.

### Short tutorial:

**General assumption:** keystrokes are going to be received in the view of a NSViewController subclass and to be processed in the view controller class

- Create a new Cocoa Class named `MyView` as a subclass of `NSView`
- Replace the contents of the created class with

  ```
  import Cocoa

  let leftArrowKey = 123
  let rightArrowKey = 124

  protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func didPressLeftArrowKey()
    func didPressRightArrowKey()
  }

  class MyView: NSView {

     var delegate : MyViewDelegate?

     override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
       let character = Int(event.keyCode)
       switch character {
       case leftArrowKey, rightArrowKey:
         break
       default:
         super.keyDown(event)
       }
     }

     override func keyUp(event: NSEvent) {
       let character = Int(event.keyCode)
       switch character {
       case leftArrowKey:
         delegate?.didPressLeftArrowKey()
       case rightArrowKey:
         delegate?.didPressRightArrowKey()
       default:
         super.keyUp(event)
       }
     }

      override var acceptsFirstResponder : Bool {
        return true
      }
    }
  ```

  - Change the class of the view of the ViewController in Interface Builder to `MyView`
  - In the ViewController class add the protocol `MyViewDelegate`- for example

    ```
    class ViewController: NSViewController, MyViewDelegate {
    ```
  - In `viewDidLoad()` add

    ```
    let view = self.view as! MyView
    view.delegate = self
    self.nextResponder = view
    ```
  - Implement the following delegate methods and add your code to switch the image(s)

    ```
    func didPressLeftArrowKey() {
      println("didPressLeftArrowKey")
      // process keystroke left arrow
    }

    func didPressRightArrowKey() {
      println("didPressRightArrowKey")
      // process keystroke right arrow
    }
    ```

The delegate methods are called when the appropriate arrow keys are released

Comment: Okay I believe I understand how that works. So the delegate methods are going in my 'ViewController' class. So how do those two lines(that would go in 'applicationDidFinishLaunching' change when I put them in a class that already has a view?

Comment: the protocol must be added to the class which processes the keystrokes and the `set delegate` line to the view controller. If the view belongs to a view controller then the class of this view must be changed to `MyView`. Then you have to reference the view this way: `let view = self.view as! MyView`

Comment: I have tried that and a few other things, still not working. I appreciate your help. By any chance do you have a working version of this code implemented in a view controller?

Comment: I edited the post to use a subclass of NSViewController. Consider the added variable `acceptsFirstResponder` in the NSView subclass

Comment: That'll be the winner! It worked. Thanks so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
let kLeftArrowKeyCode:  UInt16  = 123
let kRightArrowKeyCode: UInt16  = 124
let kDownArrowKeyCode:  UInt16  = 125
let kUpArrowKeyCode:    UInt16  = 126

override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
          switch event.keyCode {
          case kLeftArrowKeyCode:
              print("left")
              break
          case kRightArrowKeyCode:
              print("right")
              break
          case kDownArrowKeyCode:
              print("down")
              break
          case kUpArrowKeyCode:
              print("up")
              break
          default:
              print("other")
              super.keyDown(with: event)
              break
          }
          print("Key with number: \(event.keyCode) was pressed")
}
```